# indexing between states in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create an event listener which gives data to the children component.

I have two states

```
[data,setData]=useState([])
[playData,setPlayData]= useState([])
```

I get data from an API using fetch and UseEffect with [] parameter to use it only when the app launches

```
fetch(API_URL)
.then(res=>res.json)
.then(data=>setData(data))
```

in the APP component I have a children component that receives the playData and an event listener function

```
<Children data={playData} click={getDataOnClick} />
```

now i want this event listenener to send data from data as prop one by one as it is clicked ,like next next,next.. until data is exhausted

so what I do is define

```
const box = data
```

and use

```
function getDataOnClick (event){
setPlaydata(prevdata=>{
return [...prevdata,box[prevdata.length+1]]
}}
```

I get an error : box is not iterable or similar when I try braning it out with other array methods. I see that array methods donot work while iterating over states i guess?? how do i solve this?? Is there a hook that i am missing here? Also Slice doest work with state and onjects that I have made equal to the state

Comment: What exactly should `getDataOnClick` do?

Comment: it should push next item from data(state) to playData(state) , so when all items are exhausted the lists should look the same. FYI the children renders a graph which continues when a button (to which the event listnr is attached) is pressed..hope it makes sense

Comment: what about the order of the elements? Should it start from 0, 1, ...?

Comment: what is the purpose of defining `const box = data` ?

Comment: The order starts from [0] , Also a very intresting thing happens. Once I refresh the page the event works , sometimes but then if I add the same event listener to another cchildren tht does the same job with different data , everything breaks again.

Comment: Idk I just thought that manipulating state directly wouldn't be a good idea that's why i used box

Comment: The states can only be updated through setStates. React will throw an error when you update the states manually.

Comment: The over all idea was to get all the data from an API at once in the beginning (about 50 data points) and then use it to propagate a graph as the user clicks next next next ----> so on

Comment: I have used setState whenever updating, as you can see in the code @subrato

Comment: From the kinfdof errors that i am getting I think the bug is in using array methods like state.length() state.slice(start,end) and state[index] or something.

Comment: @swapnilKumar Are you sure that the data you received is an array? Can you add console .log(data) and post the output here?

Comment: data: Array(16)
0: {v: 45039, vw: 145.6109, o: 145.85, c: 145.6, h: 145.85, …}
1: {v: 17677, vw: 145.6784, o: 145.52, c: 145.69, h: 145.79, …}
2: {v: 6069, vw: 145.7286, o: 145.78, c: 145.69, h: 145.79, …}
3: {v: 11444, vw: 145.5199, o: 145.68, c: 145.35, h: 145.68, …}
4: {v: 25471, vw: 145.1503, o: 145.3, c: 145, h: 145.58, …}
5: {v: 12481, vw: 145.0665, o: 145.01, c: 145.12, h: 145.2, …}
6: {v: 10981, vw: 145.1586, o: 145.1, c: 145.22, h: 145.45, …}
7: {v: 23728, vw: 145.1844, o: 145.22, c: 145.25, h: 145.4, …}
8: {v: 11875, vw: 145.1789, o: 145.3, c: 145.08, h: 145.3, …}
....

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `prevdata.length` instead of `prevdata.length + 1` or else you will be skipping one element. And you can check if `playData` has all the elements that are in `data` before pushing more.

I created a sandbox that does what you're trying to do.

[image: Edit confident-glade-9x6e1]

```
function Child({ onNext, playData }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{playData}</p>
      <button onClick={onNext}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [playData, setPlayData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fakePromise = Promise.resolve(
      Array(50)
        .fill()
        .map((_, i) => i)
    );
    (async () => {
      setData(await fakePromise);
    })();
  }, []);

  const onNext = () => {
    setPlayData((prev) =>
      data.length === prev.length ? prev : [...prev, data[prev.length]]
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child playData={playData} onNext={onNext} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: same :( says prev is not iterable

Comment: @swapnilKumar can you create a sandbox replicating the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-carlos-bghqk?file=/src/App.js Now the same code works here ... thats strange